# How Nginx proxy handle internal redirection

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have a problem to understand how nginx proxy_pass will handle the redirection after the URL getting rewrite.

What I have is `localhost:8080/foo/log` will automatically redirect to `localhost:8080/foo/login`. Once you enter the right credentials it will redirect back to `localhost:8080/foo/log`

```
localhost:8080/foo/log -----> localhost:8080/foo/login
```

I have a nginx proxy server to change my URL from `localhost:8080/foo/log` to `localhost/web/foo/log` with following configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location /web/foo {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        rewrite ^/web/foo(.*) /foo$1 break;
    }

    location /web/bar {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
        rewrite ^/web/bar(.*) /bar$1 break;
    }
}
```

With this proxy config, I am ok to see`localhost/web/foo/log` proxy from  `localhost:8080/foo/log` without enabling login redirection. If I enabled login, I always get `localhost/web/foofoo/login`.

I am wondering how can I get `localhost/web/foo/login` proxy from `localhost:8080/foo/login` ?